# How do I get the scrollView contentOffset of a UICollectionView for a horizontal collectionView?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I am trying to retrieve the **contentOffset** property of a **scrollView** for my horizontally scrollable UICollectionView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the x coordinate of the contentOffset you need to use **scrollView.contentOffset.x**.